# How can I use router.activate() with an ID specified?

Tags: durandal

I have the following routes mapped:

```
        router.map([
            { url: 'error', moduleId: 'viewmodels/error', name: 'Error', visible: false },
            { url: 'home', moduleId: 'viewmodels/home', name: 'Home', visible: false },
            { url: 'folder/:id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/folder', name: 'Folder', visible: false },
            { url: 'set/:id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/set', name: 'Set', visible: false }

        ]);
```

after I map these routes, I activate the router.  Currently I'm doing:

```
return router.activate('home');
```

but I'd like to do something like

```
return router.activate('folder/2');
```

however I get the following error with that:

```
GET http://localhost:11089/App/viewmodels/folder/2.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could be wrong but i believe that the current router might not support this.

You should use router.navigateTo instead.

But i think you found your answer on the google groups :D

For others:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/3QxMsJjsy1s
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/durandaljs/router.activate/durandaljs/3QxMsJjsy1s/TUomWbMSrQgJ

Comment: NavigateTo isn't really an option - I can't be loading one view and then another.  Seems like a lousy UX to me.  Thanks for the links though - I posted up a follow-up question there to hopefully get an answer.